# How to use Use List<T>.RemoveAll to simplify for loop and remove items from collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have this implementation below. It uses a for loop. Is there a way to eliminate the for loop and simplify the code using C# List Extensions?

```
public class Member
{
    public string member { get; set; }
}

public class PatternMatch
{
    public static List<Member> Remove()
    {
        var prefix = new string[] { "usa-", "o-", "a-" };

        var members = new List<Member>();
        members.Add(new Member { member = "a-o@b.com" });
        members.Add(new Member { member = "usa-b@d.com" });
        members.Add(new Member { member = "c@d.com" });

        // don't use foreach since we will be modifying the collection 
        for (var i = members.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            foreach (var pattern in prefix)
            {
                if (members[i].member.StartsWith(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    members.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return members;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn’t it the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251958/listt-removeall-does-not-work-on-list-objects

Comment: no this is different. I am not sure how to write it using List extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveAll` implementation could look like this

```
members.RemoveAll(x => prefix.Any(p => x.member.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
```

`RemoveAll` removes every item that matches the given `Predicate<T>`.

A `Predicate<T>` is very basically a method with a parameter of `T` and a return type of `bool`.

So the above code could be re-written as

```
members.RemoveAll(ConditionToRemove);
bool ConditionToRemove(Member x) => true;
```

The condition

```
x => prefix.Any(p => x.member.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Does the following

for every `T` - I declared it as the variable `x` - it will check if their is `Any` entry in the list `prefix` that has the condition of

```
x.member.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

So, `prefix.Any` will return `true` if there is atleast one entry `x.member` starts with.

Comment: Rand Random: could you please explain how the RemoveAll works?

Comment: @blogs4t - hope I could explain it understandable

Comment: @blogs4t just be careful, `RemoveAll` mutates the original list, so if he predicate (ConditionToRemove) throws an exception (for instance, if x.member is null), it will corrupt the list.

Answer (score 0):

With Linq, something like this will work:

```
return members
    .Where(m => !prefix
        .Any(p  => m.member.StartsWith(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```